# PHP simplexml -- formatting integers

Tags: php, variables, formatting, integer, simplexml

I'm using simplexml to recover xml from a remote server, and I get values that can look something like this:

1.28586732

-1.2357956

I save these values in a variable but I would like to:

1. Display each value with no more than 2 decimal places
2. Have a plus sign precede the value if it is positive
3. Apply different CSS styles depending on whether the value is positive or negative (for instance display value in red if it is negative)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display only 2 decimal places you can either use `round($num, 2)` or `sprintf("%.2f", $num)`, the difference is that `sprintf` always returns 2 decimal places, i.e. `5` would be `5.00`, while `round` only shows the necessary amount of decimal places. `sprintf` is also locale-aware.

To have a plus sign precede the value, you would simply do `if ($num >= 0) $num = '+'.$num;`

And finally to do CSS styling, you should wrap the number in a span and give it a class, i.e. either `positive` or `negative`.

To do all of the three, you could have a function like this:

```
function format_decimal($num)
{
    return sprintf(
        '<span class="%s">%+.2f</span>',
        $num < 0 ? 'negative' : 'positive',
        $num
    );
}
```

Comment: @stereofrog: good catch, that's a nicer way to do it, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

let:

```
$s=1.2344545665

if($s>=0)
{
echo "<div class=\"addclass\">+".roundDigits($s,2) . "</div>";
}
else
{
echo "<div class=\"minusclass\">-".roundDigits($s,2) . "</div>";
}
```

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after the variable definition. What is `roundDigits`, I think you mean `round`. Why are you prepending a negative sign on a negative number when it's there implicitly? There's a lot of errors in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out number_format. http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php Then if >= 0 for a positive, <= negative checks.

Comment: You may wish to typecast it first then into either (float) or (double).